# How to get back the name passed to ID3D12Object::SetName()?

Tags: directx-12

There's a setter, but no getter. [The doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12object-setname) doesn't give any information other than that this name will be used in debug diagnostics and tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```cpp
wchar_t name[128] = {};
UINT size = sizeof(name);
object->GetPrivateData(WKPDID_D3DDebugObjectNameW, &size, name);
```

In DX11 the `SetName` API didn't exist, but `SetPrivateData(WKPDID_D3DDebugObjectName, ...)` was used for the same purpose. And `GetPrivateData` could be used to retrieve the string.

DX12 actually uses the same system, just with a different GUID because the name is in unicode (note the `W` at the end of `WKPDID_D3DDebugObjectNameW`), and `SetName` is just a shortcut for it.